# JFrame as a dialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I want to customize the jframe and that frame should work like a joptionpane. which is relative with parent. can i do like this. if it is possible please any one help me.

Comment: _I want to customize the jframe and make it as a dialog_ Why? Is `JDialog` an option?

Comment: May you please explain a bit more, as to what is the requirement ? Why to reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: i want design a form in a frame and i want to make setopacity,setundecorated,etc..., to that frame but it should work like a joptionpane which means without responding this window we cant touch any window in software.

Answer (score 3):

With a little [bit of research, the answer to your question](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) is more accessible than you think.

No use reinventing the wheel. Just use a `JDialog` instead of a hacked `JFrame`.

Also, please consider putting a little bit more effort in your questions. The quality of answers mirror the quality of the question.

Comment: My think is that he already know about `JDialog`, i think he wants to reinvent the wheel

Comment: thnk u for ur reply. i want to customize the jframe and that jframe should work as a joptionpane. because i want to design the frame with setundecorated, setOpacity, etc,....

Answer (score 1):

Below are a few examples of Dialogs with JFrames.  Trying to customize a JFrame with a dialog is likely to be very unnecessary as these are just a few from a large range of dialogs you can utilize.

Also as GCrec has referenced, there are the tutorials on Oracle which can give you more of a description.

```
  public class SO {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Shows a GUI to allow typed input        
    String showInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(new JFrame(), "Enter some input:");
    //Shows a GUI displaying a message, in this case the typed input
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), showInput);
    //A confirmation dialog for choosing yes or no
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(new JFrame(), "Was that correct?");
    //Options for the below GUI where you have a range of options.  The int response 
    //varies depending on what you select. Then use something like an if statement to react to the input
    String[] options = {"Red", "Blue", "Green"};
     int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog( null, "Favorite Colour?", "Choice?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION    , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE , null, options, "Wide Search");


    //The one you probably want, the JDialog which is basically a JFrame with a file selection dialog inside         
     FileDialog fc = new FileDialog(new JFrame(), "File Dialog");
    fc.setVisible(true);
    String selectedFile = fc.getFile();
     System.out.println("You have selected: " + selectedFile);
     File f = new File(selectedFile);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Hope this helps!
Good luck

Comment: thnk u for ur reply. i want to customize the jframe and that jframe should work as a joptionpane. because i want to design the frame with setundecorated, setOpacity, etc,....

Comment: Sounds like you may want to look into extending JOPtionpane class if you want it to be based from there

Comment: i am not sure wat u saying. if i get some examples it will be great. thanks in advance

Comment: i want design a form in a frame and i want to make setopacity,setundecorated,etc..., to that frame but it should work like a joptionpane which means without responding this window we cant touch any window in software.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to go about such a task.  You want to keep the focus on your JFrame like a JOPtion pane.  Potentially a solution with a focus listener could be workable, or possibly creating a class which extends the JOPtion pane class, but they would both take a lot of looking into to.